# VUE3: params used to select which data in composition API to populate the data in a component binded by :post

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am currently working on a view that has a component that relies on bound information. The problem I am having is finding the right syntax to use with `:post`. I have set up the Composition API, and set a `const val = props.id`, which is a param I have sent over from the previous page. If I `console.log(val)`, the word is correct, but when I bind, it doesn't perform as if I wrote the word in myself. So if I write `<component-foo :post="Notes" />`, everything works fine. But if I write `<component-foo :post="val" />`, where `const val = props.id` in the Composition API, it fails to load.

Here is the code that I have written:

```html
<template>
  <focused-section :post="val" />
</template>

<script>
import FocusedSection from '@/components/FocusedSection.vue';
 
export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: 'FocusedView',
  components: { FocusedSection },
  props: ['id'],
  setup(props) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-setup-props-destructure
    const val = props.id;
    const Notes = {
      title: 'ChiroWrite Notes',
      photo: 'notes-image',
      alt: 'Image of someone taking notes',
      overview: 'ChiroWrite is designed ...',
      features: {
        feature1: 'some info',
        feature2: 'some info',
        feature3: 'some info',
        feature4: 'some info',
        feature5: 'some info',
        feature6: 'some info',
      },
      productPhoto: 'patient-notes',
      ppAlt: 'Example screen of Chirowrite notes.',
    };
 
    const Scheduler = {
      title: 'ChiroWrite Scheduler',
      photo: 'schedule-image',
      alt: 'Graphic representation of a schedule',
      overview: 'The ChiroWrite Scheduler...',
      features: {
        feature1: 'some info',
        feature2: 'some info',
        feature3: 'some info',
        feature4: 'some info',
      },
      productPhoto: 'scheduler-default',
      ppAlt: 'Example image of the scheduler screen.',
    };
 
    const Billing = {
      title: 'ChiroWrite Billing',
      photo: 'billing-image',
      alt: 'Graphic representation of billing',
      overview: 'The ChiroWrite billing...',
      features: {
        feature1: 'some info',
        feature2: 'some info',
        feature3: 'some info',
      },
      productPhoto: 'scheduler-text',
      ppAlt: 'Example image of the billing screen',
    };
 
    return {
      Notes,
      Scheduler,
      Billing,
      val,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: `val` is not reactive. You should define it as `const val = ref(props.id);`

Comment: thanks for this. I've done this, but I am realizing maybe this a problem, but not the problem. I'm trying to research how this is loaded in the DOM, because it doesn't load the information, but if i console.log the value of the variable it is correct. So maybe the page is loaded it looks like :post="". then after the page is loaded, props.id is assigned to val, but at this point it's too late.

Comment: An `id` sounds like a string or number (and you called it a "word", so it's probably a string), but you've copied it into `val`, and then bound that to `<focused-section>.post`, which is likely expecting an object (not a string). That seems to be the problem to me.

Comment: ok, i think i understand now. :post is actually looking for the object to load into the component. My logic currently is attaching the name of the object (Notes, Scheduler, Billing) to val. I was under the impression that the value attached to :post would be a reference of which object to use. I would have to change my logic all together to get this to work as desired. Thanks.